# JSRender cannot read property 'Description' of undefined

Tags: javascript, templates, nested, jsrender

I have this code on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3VN/6/ that's not working properly.

On my machine it gives the message: Error: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined.

Does any know what should I do to reach the right results?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You misspelled `bandwidth` in a few places.

Comment: Thank you jbabey...that was the point!

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/Ue3VN/10/

Aside form a few typos, the newest builds of jsRedner use a slightly diffrent syntax:

```
{{if someCondition}}
{{:somevalue}}
{{>htmlEncodedValue}}
```

You also don't need to escape the quotes when adding jsRender values into attributes.